# Show perf report with events grouped by thread id?

Tags: performance, optimization, x86, perf

I would like to use Perf to measure L3 cache accesses/misses and all context switch events, per each thread. No sampling, just the raw counter totals.

However, I prefer to avoid looking up thread IDs whilst the application is running.

I get the impression Perf has a data-collection stage, separate from data visualization stage.

Is it possible to record the statistics first and then show the results per thread?

Do I first run `sudo perf record -e [events] ./my_app`?

Then afterwards I run `sudo perf report` but how do I list the thread ids I am interested in, or instruct perf to group by thread id?